# Which sentence sounds better? Grammatical question about sentences

Tags: grammar, word-choice, differences, word-order

I seriously can't tell which sounds natural in English. Need some help.

> a) From tomorrow on, she'll be coming to our place to work with us.
>
> b) She'll be coming to our place to work with us, from tomorrow on.

If there are better answers, suggestions, anything is welcome.

Not a must but preferable:

1. I'd like to use them in casual conversations between friends.
2. Shorter sentences will help. Long lines won't fit.

Answer (score 2):

I hear sentences similar to the first one more often in a natural context, and indeed, that modifier you are adding is in regards to "she," so you want to make the modifier as close to the subject as possible for clarity. I would, however, in regards to what is natural, say "starting tomorrow" instead of "from tomorrow on"; the former is more casual.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer!